# Why does my 2007 Lexus ES350 have a sticky dash

Tags: interior, lexus

I recently bought a 2007 Lexus ES350 nice car but the dash has some sticky stuff on it that

Comment: Why? Because something was spilt on it:-) Are you asking how to clean your dash?

Comment: Some plastics degrade, over time, into a sticky mess. Ask anyone who uses a computer mouse that has one of those "soft touch rubber feel" coatings; in about 10 years of being covered in oils from human skin it too will be something you don't want to touch :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [long known issue with dashboards](http://www.toyotaproblems.com/melting-dashboard/) from 2006-2008 Lexus ES & IS's (also affects the 2007-2009 Toyota Camry). Under the heat and sun they get shiny and sticky, with very little which can be done about it except replacement. Luckily, Toyota had a recall program named: *customer support program ZE6*. If this has never been done on your vehicle, it still may be a valid recall, meaning you should be able to get the dash replaced for free.